# Optimize the Algotithm

Tags: c#, list, optimization

So, i have a method

```
public void AddToSearch(List<FullName> fullNames)
        {
            foreach (var fullName in fullNames)
            {
                if (fullName.Surname != null)
                    _sb.Append(fullName.Surname.Trim() + " ");
                if (fullName.Name != null)
                    _sb.Append(fullName.Name.Trim() + " ");
                if (fullName.Patronymic != null)
                    _sb.Append(fullName.Patronymic.Trim());
                fullNamesList.Add(_sb.ToString().TrimEnd());
                _sb.Clear();
            }
```

it takes a list of FullName and by using StringBuilder instance converts each element into a string(which format is "$Surname $Name $Patronymic"). At the end i put the result into my list. The Question is - how can i optimize  all of that "Trim" stuff. It bothers me that i use it in multiple occassions and i am pretty sure it effects the time.

Comment: "i am pretty sure it effects the time" Did you **measure** that using a benchmark-test? This is executing that code sme millions of time?

Comment: I actually measured it and it takes around 23210 nanoseconds to execute

Comment: You could create a new stringbuilder on every iteration instead of resetting the existing one again and again usinjg `Clear`. But I don't know if that helps much

Comment: There is no need to optimize this code. It's good to go to production.

Comment: 23210 nanoseconds for how many iterations? I have no clue if that is much in your context or completely neglectable.

Comment: How about overriding the `tostring` in `FullName` then there's no need to do this. [See more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) there.

Comment: One improvement would be to `Append` the space between words as well. Speaking of which, if you properly manage addition of the spaces between words (which you are not currently), you won't need the call to `TrimEnd`.

Comment: @Trevor that won't help on getting rid of all those `Trim`-calls for all those properties I suppose.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain why not, the setters can handle that...

Comment: a problem is that this task is from russian forum and it has hidden tests. Idk how many iterations it consists of. The only thing i have is the time which it took to finish all the tests.

Comment: Why are untrimmed strings stored in the FullName class?  Why not Trim them when storing in the FullName?

Comment: than you should use a profiling-tool, e.g. DotTrace to indicate where exactly you missed the tests.

Comment: @Wyck see my comment, I said that in response to MakePeaceGreatAgain.. `setters can handle that` => `that won't help on getting rid of all those Trim-calls`.

Comment: Put the Trim in the setter of your properties: `private string _name; public string Name { get => _name; set => _name = value?.Trim(); }`

Comment: @Iceneo another option is to remove the `foreach` loop and call `fullNamesList.AddRange(fullNames);` if you override the to string as I mentioned above... Potentially you don't even need this routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the strings normalization process should be done in the data layer (in application or database) for stored strings. While dynamic strings such as user input, needs to be normalized as soon as you get them to prepare them for the next task.

For your current code, you can modify the `FullName` class, adjust the setters to trim the value before it's been stored, and override the `ToString` to return the full name.

Example :

```
public class FullName
{       
    public string Name 
    {
        get => Name;
        set => Name = value?.Trim();
    }
    
    public string Surname 
    {
        get => Surname;
        set => Surname = value?.Trim();
    }
    
    public string Patronymic 
    {
        get => Patronymic;
        set => Patronymic = value?.Trim();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{GetValueOrEmpty(Surname)}{GetValueOrEmpty(Name)}{GetValueOrEmpty(Patronymic, false)}";
    }
    
    private string GetValueOrEmpty(string name, bool addSpaceAfter = true)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            return name + (addSpaceAfter ? " " : string.Empty);
        }
        
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Then, you can do this :

```
fullNamesList.AddRange(fullNames.Select(x=> x.ToString()));
```

### UPDATE :

Thanks to @olivier-jacot-descombes, the above code is missing the use of [backing fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields), which will avoid causing overflow exception by the properties infinite recursions. The following adjustments will do the trick.

```
public class FullName
{      
    private string _name;
    private string _surname;
    private string _patronymic;
    
    public string Name 
    {
        get => _name;
        set => _name = value?.Trim();
    }
    
    public string Surname 
    {
        get => _surname;
        set => _surname = value?.Trim();
    }
    
    public string Patronymic 
    {
        get => _patronymic;
        set => _patronymic = value?.Trim();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{GetValueOrEmpty(Surname)}{GetValueOrEmpty(Name)}{GetValueOrEmpty(Patronymic, false)}";
    }
    
    private string GetValueOrEmpty(string name, bool addSpaceAfter = true)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            return name + (addSpaceAfter ? " " : string.Empty);
        }
        
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have introduced endless recursions by returning or setting the properties themselves instead of the backing fields.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thanks, I have added an update to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> how can i optimize all of that "Trim" stuff

Very simple, simply don't call `Trim()` on those strings. What spaces are you worried about? Who's entering those values in your business objects? Because short of solar flares randomly flipping bits enough to append spaces to your strings, you're in full control from beginning to end, so simply don't add the spaces.

You also don't need the two string builders, just insert in your main one. There's no need for yet another `Trim()` here either, because simply decrementing the `Length` property of your string builder is a constant operation (it literally decrements one integer with guaranteed no extra allocations).

Comment: "Who's entering those values in your business objects?" That's a really good question. Depending on that the "issue" becomes not an issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try and extension something like this.

```
public static class Helper
{
  public static StringBuilder AppendValue(this StringBuilder builder,string value)
  {
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
      builder.Append(value.Trim());
      return builder;
    }
  }
}
```

call as follows:

```
sb.AppendValue(fullName.Name);
sb.AppendValue(fullName.Surname);
...
```

You will get the StringBuilder back with the value if it is not empty otherwise nothing will be added to it.